# Cant edit body using css

Tags: html, css

i cant edit my body background or anything about my body from my css file. does anyone know why this might be. I know the CSS file is linked properly as it edits the table. its only the body that wont edit. please can someone tell me why this is happening.

*ive had to remove some of the html code as it was aparetly too long however this is unrelated to the issue*

```
<style>

body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
}



</style>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script src="js.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</link>

<body>
  <div1>
    <header>
      <h1 id="header">Noah's Address book</h1>
    </header>

    <div id="tableside">
      <div id="searchside">
        <label for="searching">Search for address</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="searching" name="searching" required><br>

      </div>
      <div id="table">
        <table id="table1">

        </table>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div1>
  <script>
    $("#adContact").on("submit", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var $fname = $("#fname");
      var fname = $fname.val();
      var $lname = $("#lname");
      var lname = $lname.val();
      var $numb = $("#numb");
      var numb = $numb.val();
      var $adr = $("#adr");
      var adr = $adr.val();
      if (nameTest(fname, lname) === false) {
        $("#error").text("First and Last name must only contain letters");
      } else if (numTest(numb) === false) {
        $("#error").text("Number can only contain numbers and must be in 00000000000 format");
      } else if (firstLength(fname) === false) {
        $("#error").text("First name input too long");
      } else if (lastLength(lname) === false) {
        $("#error").text("Last name input too long");
      } else if (addressLength(adr) === false) {
        $("#error").text("Address input too long, please keep input below 100 characters ");
      } else if (alreadyActive(fname, lname, numb) === false) {
        $("#error").text("contact already exists");
      } else {
        $("#error").text("contact added");
        newContact(fname, lname, numb, adr);
      }
      reload()
    })
    $("#removeContact").on("submit", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var $numb1 = $("#numb1");
      var numb1 = $numb1.val();
      var $fname1 = $("#fname1");
      var fname1 = $fname1.val();
      var $lname1 = $("#lname1");
      var lname1 = $lname1.val();
      if (removeContact(fname1, lname1, numb1) === false) {
        $("#error1").text("Contact not found");
      } else {
        $("#error1").text("Contact removed");
      }
      reload()
    })
    var row = "<tr><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th><th>Number</th><th>Address</th></tr>"
    $("#table1").append(row)
    var contactListOriginall = addressLogLength()
    for (let i = 0; i < contactListOriginall.length; i++) {
      let contactName = contactListOriginall[i]
      var firstname = getData(contactName)[0];
      var lastname = getData(contactName)[1]
      var number = getData(contactName)[2]
      var address = getData(contactName)[3]
      let row = "<tr id=contactName><th>" + firstname + "</th><th>" + lastname + "</th><th>" + number + "</th><th>" + address + "</th></tr>"
      $("#table1").append(row)
    }

    function reload() {
      $("#table1 tr").remove()
      let row = "<tr><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th><th>Number</th><th>Address</th></tr>"
      $("#table1").append(row)
      var $search = $("#searching");
      var search = $search.val();
      let contactList = match(search)
      for (let c = 0; c < contactList.length; c++) {
        let contactName = contactList[c]
        var firstname = getData(contactName)[0];
        var lastname = getData(contactName)[1]
        var number = getData(contactName)[2]
        var address = getData(contactName)[3]
        let row = "<tr id=contactName><th>" + firstname + "</th><th>" + lastname + "</th><th>" + number + "</th><th>" + address + "</th></tr>"
        $("#table1").append(row)
      }
    }
    $("#searching").on("input", function() {
      reload()
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: `<div1>` is not a valid element and it's the only child of `<body>` so the browser is probably having a hard time negotiating the page. Change `<div1>` to `<div>` and any CSS rulesets involved with `div1`. I'm pretty sure someone already pointed out the lack of `<head>`, `<html>`, etc?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need "style" tags because these tags only used in .html file to make .html understand that these are css codes.

Also, you may need to add "head" tags at the bottom and above like that:

```
<head>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    </link>
</head>
```

If it still doesn't work add html tags like that:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
    </link>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div1>
        <header>
          <h1 id="header">Noah's Address book</h1>
        </header>
    
        <div id="tableside">
          <div id="searchside">
            <label for="searching">Search for address</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="searching" name="searching" required><br>
    
          </div>
          <div id="table">
            <table id="table1">
    
            </table>
          </div>
    
        </div>
      </div1>
      <script>
        $("#adContact").on("submit", function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var $fname = $("#fname");
          var fname = $fname.val();
          var $lname = $("#lname");
          var lname = $lname.val();
          var $numb = $("#numb");
          var numb = $numb.val();
          var $adr = $("#adr");
          var adr = $adr.val();
          if (nameTest(fname, lname) === false) {
            $("#error").text("First and Last name must only contain letters");
          } else if (numTest(numb) === false) {
            $("#error").text("Number can only contain numbers and must be in 00000000000 format");
          } else if (firstLength(fname) === false) {
            $("#error").text("First name input too long");
          } else if (lastLength(lname) === false) {
            $("#error").text("Last name input too long");
          } else if (addressLength(adr) === false) {
            $("#error").text("Address input too long, please keep input below 100 characters ");
          } else if (alreadyActive(fname, lname, numb) === false) {
            $("#error").text("contact already exists");
          } else {
            $("#error").text("contact added");
            newContact(fname, lname, numb, adr);
          }
          reload()
        })
        $("#removeContact").on("submit", function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          var $numb1 = $("#numb1");
          var numb1 = $numb1.val();
          var $fname1 = $("#fname1");
          var fname1 = $fname1.val();
          var $lname1 = $("#lname1");
          var lname1 = $lname1.val();
          if (removeContact(fname1, lname1, numb1) === false) {
            $("#error1").text("Contact not found");
          } else {
            $("#error1").text("Contact removed");
          }
          reload()
        })
        var row = "<tr><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th><th>Number</th><th>Address</th></tr>"
        $("#table1").append(row)
        var contactListOriginall = addressLogLength()
        for (let i = 0; i < contactListOriginall.length; i++) {
          let contactName = contactListOriginall[i]
          var firstname = getData(contactName)[0];
          var lastname = getData(contactName)[1]
          var number = getData(contactName)[2]
          var address = getData(contactName)[3]
          let row = "<tr id=contactName><th>" + firstname + "</th><th>" + lastname + "</th><th>" + number + "</th><th>" + address + "</th></tr>"
          $("#table1").append(row)
        }
    
        function reload() {
          $("#table1 tr").remove()
          let row = "<tr><th>First name</th><th>Last name</th><th>Number</th><th>Address</th></tr>"
          $("#table1").append(row)
          var $search = $("#searching");
          var search = $search.val();
          let contactList = match(search)
          for (let c = 0; c < contactList.length; c++) {
            let contactName = contactList[c]
            var firstname = getData(contactName)[0];
            var lastname = getData(contactName)[1]
            var number = getData(contactName)[2]
            var address = getData(contactName)[3]
            let row = "<tr id=contactName><th>" + firstname + "</th><th>" + lastname + "</th><th>" + number + "</th><th>" + address + "</th></tr>"
            $("#table1").append(row)
          }
        }
        $("#searching").on("input", function() {
          reload()
        });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the surrounding `<style>` tags as they aren't needed because you are already in a styles file.

**Inside `css.css`:**

```
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```